# Decorators in Composer Modelling language

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I am able to understand the use of decorator in transaction processor file.

Could you please provide the complete samples of decorator applied on the resource in the .cto file and accessed in the other file.

https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/reference/cto_language.html

Answer (score 0):

Info -> https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/reference/js_scripts.html

Samples ->

eg. Perishables network example use of decorators in script file

https://github.com/hyperledger/composer-sample-networks/blob/master/packages/perishable-network/lib/logic.js

Decorators used in the model files eg.

```
@foo("arg1", 2)
participant Buyer extends Person {
}
```

Accessing it in the code could be (example):

```
const val = myField.getDecorator('foo').getArguments()[2];
```

ie retrieve the 3rd argument to the foo decorator attached to the myField property of a class declaration:

Comment: Thank you, Paul.  Can you show me a sample, on how to use the decorators in model file and use it in transaction file?

Comment: hi, decorators in the model file with some samples is covered here -> https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/issues/2157 - I believe here it also has examples of how to access the decorators using standard Javascript APIs  - I've added an example in the answer (edited above)